# Using typewriter font and turning off hyphenation in ConTeXt

Tags: fonts, context, context-mkiv, typewriter

I want to set the font for my entire document as a courier / typewriter font, so that it resembles a typewritten manuscript.

This includes turning off hyphenation for the entire document.

So far, I have tried this:

```
\usetypescript[courier][uc]
\setupbodyfont[courier,12pt]

\setupalign [nothyphenated]
```

Though this gives me what I want, I find that ConTeXt is being excesively tolerant with it, extending words far beyond reasonable limits, even cutting words when reaching the end of paper.

Is there anything more I can do?

Comment: Use ragged text instead of justified: `\setupalign[nothyphenated, right]`

Comment: By checking the wiki I see that this option left aligns the text... I thought this was the default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Turning off hyphenation makes it very hard for TeX to justify paragraphs.  Overfull and underfull boxes are the result.  One can help TeX here by allowing the text to be set with a ragged edge.  This is achieved by `\setupalign[flushleft]`.

```
\showframe
\setupbodyfont[cursor,12pt]
\setupalign[nothyphenated,flushleft]
\starttext
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

[image]